# Export composer to single PDF file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

I am using PyQGIS to create automated maps.

My script exports atlas features to new JPG images. But I need now to export my features to single PDF file all my features like option where have qi's composer in atlas define.

Here to code for export to my features:

```
for i in range(0, myAtlas.numFeatures()):
    myAtlas.prepareForFeature(i)
    jobs = r"C:/Users/username/Desktop/test/"
    output_jpeg = jobs + str(i)+ "_BMS_plan.jpg"
    myImage = myComposition.printPageAsRaster(0)
    myImage.save(output_jpeg)
myAtlas.endRender()
```

How should I change this code?